# Access single query result without a f:for loop in Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I am looking for a better way of printing query results in my fluid template when I know there is only one result. For example, I am getting a dataset with a specific ID from the database and want to print it. My current way would be:

```
<f:for each="{scripts}" as="script">
    {script.title}
</f:for>
```

Where in the Controller I have:

```
$this->view->assign('scripts', $this->msRepository->getScript($scriptId));
```

Which calls this query:

```
return $this->dbHandle->sql_query("SELECT * FROM script WHERE id = $scriptId");
```

So I am 100% certain there is only one entry in `{scripts}`, still I need to loop through it with an `f:for` loop. Is there a better way?

I tried  `{scripts.0.title}` but got a blank output. Extensive Google search did not yield any results for me.

**Edit**: It works when changing the query to:

```
return $this->dbHandle->sql_query("SELECT * FROM script WHERE id = $scriptId")->fetch_array();
```

Then I can access the value with `{scripts.title}`.

Comment: Why not simple modify your "getScript" function so it returns the first object if you only want one object?

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. Adding my solution to the question

Answer (score 2):

Like you assumed: `{scripts.0.title}` should do the job.

Comment: Hm, I tried that before and there was just a blank output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you just add a `<f:debug>{scripts}</f:debug>` and have a look what keys you see. Just to be sure that there is a `scripts.0`

Comment: I am getting this: `mysqli_resultprototypeobject
   current_field => 0 (integer)
   field_count => 3 (integer)
   lengths => NULL
   num_rows => 1 (integer)
   type => 0 (integer)`. For `<f:debug>{scripts.0}</f:debug>` it only shows a `NULL`

Comment: Did the stuff work with `<f:for>`? `sql_query` returns a `bool||object MySQLi result object / DBAL object` you should assign it to a variable and use `sql_fetch_row` to get an array returned. Then `{scripts.0.title}` should work.

Comment: Yes, it worked with `<f:for>`. I have now converted it to an array by hand in the PHP code. Now it works fine with just `{scripts.title}`